# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters'

Tags: c#, database, forms, sql-update, oledb

I been used this code just fine in another table but in this one, I can't use it because of this error. I can't figure out the problem. I need your help.
This is what my database looks like:

[image]

And this is the design of the database. Translation of data types are:

```
Auto number
Number
short text
short text
short text
Number
```

[image]

```
private void button_degistir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value);
    OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= hasta_bilgisi.accdb");
    baglanti.Open();
    OleDbCommand guncelle_komut = new OleDbCommand("update tbl_Randevu set randevu_hasta_id=@hastaninid,teşhis=@teshis,tedavi=@tedav,randevu_tarihi=@randevu_tarih,verilen_ilaç_id=@ilacid where randevu_hasta_id=@x", baglanti);
    guncelle_komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hastaninid", textBox_hastaid.Text);
    guncelle_komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teshis", textBox_teshis.Text);
    guncelle_komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tedav", textBox_tedavi.Text);
    guncelle_komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@randevu_tarih", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
    guncelle_komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ilacid", comboBox_ilac.SelectedIndex.ToString());
                
    
    MessageBox.Show(guncelle_komut.ExecuteNonQuery() + "adet güncellendi");
    baglanti.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the error, you forgot to add the id parameter;

```
guncelle_komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", id);
```

But it seems there is one more problem if I understand your code & table design correctly. You're using randevu_hasta_id for the `id` parameter which is `@x`. But that's not a unique id. It's a recurring field. If you use `randevu_hasta_id`, all rows that have the same `randevu_hasta_id` will be updated. Not just one. Your unique id is `randevu_id`. You should use that field if you want to update one specific row.

Comment: Thank you you were right. I fixed the issue thank you mimozz

Comment: No problem & have a nice one Yakup =)
And RBT, thanks for the edit and the nice example about readability =)